# In Ubuntu 15.04, how do I disable the hints in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, 15.04

So, I just updated to 15.04. Looks great, but the first thing I noticed when opening up a terminal was that it reads:

```
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.
```

This is very irritating because I know perfectly well how to use a terminal. How can I disable this?